# Perl Script not running correctly

Tags: perl

When ever I run this bit of code. it doesn't display any output. Anyone see anything wrong?
I am trying to display this in the out put:

```
A
AA
AAA
AAAB
AAABA
AAABAA
AAABAAA
AAABAAAB
```

etc.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$A = 3;
$B = 1;
$i = 1;
$output = "";
$j = 1;

while ($i <= $ARGV[0]) {
 while ($j <= $i) {
if ($A == 0 && $B == 0) {
  $A = 3;
  $B = 1;
}

if ($A > 0) {
  $output.= "A";
  $A--;
}
else {
  $output.= "B";
  $B--;
}

$j++;
 }

 print($output  .  "\n");
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to pass an argument? (This would have been caught if you had used `use strict; use warnings;` as you always should.)

Comment: check if it's even going in here with arguments : while ($i <= $ARGV[0])

Comment: When useing the stict tag it tells me "use of uninitialized value in numeric le (<=) at line 11

Comment: @DrMonocle any updates to your issue? Has a provided answer helped you out?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when I run it with a numeric argument (number of lines).

An idea how to simplify the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $count = shift;
my $A = 3;
my $B = 1;
my $string = q();
$string .= ('A' x $A) . ('B' x $B) while $count > length $string;
print substr($string, 0, $_), "\n" for 1 .. $count;
```

It uses a different algorithm - it creates the longest possible string, and then outputs parts of it.

Comment: `$string = ('A' x $A . 'B' x $B) x (1+($count-1)/($A+$B));`

Answer (score 0):

if there is no `@ARGV`, `while ($i <= $ARGV[0])` never runs.

`@ARGV` is an array of the command line arguments provided when the script is executed. you did not provide any command line arguments. if you had `use warnings` in effect, you would be warned that `$ARGV[0]` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

As from `ikegami` comment. You cann't pass the input at when the program is compile. For example, consider your file name is `algo.pl`. Can you run your program with

```
 perl algo.pl 10
```

Here 10 is the input value of the program. In program value is retrieve  by the `$ARGV[0]`

so in your program looks like `while ($i <= $ARGV[0])`.

If you want pass the several values like `perl  filename.pl 12 data1 data2`In your data retrieve by  `$ARGV[0] $ARGV[1] $ARGV[2]` for more information [see here](http://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl).

If you want pass the input at the time of execution used `STDIN`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $A = 3;
my $B = 1;
my $i = 1;
my $output = "";
my $j = 1;

print "Enter the value: ";
chomp(my $value = <STDIN>);


while ($i <= $value) {
 while ($j <= $i) {
if ($A == 0 && $B == 0) {
  $A = 3;
  $B = 1;
}

if ($A > 0) {
  $output.= "A";
  $A--;
}
else {
  $output.= "B";
  $B--;
}

$j++;
 }

 print($output  .  "\n");
  $i++;
}
```